# Python: Change Logic Operator on the fly

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I have begun delving deeper into Python and currently have a code snippet that looks like this while working on an assignment:

```py
if conditionA:
    if x > y:
    // perform action

elif conditionB:
    if x >= y:
    // perform same action

else:
    pass
```

In other words, depending on whether `conditionA` or `conditionB` is true (they cannot both be true, but they can both be false) I want to check the nested condition that is very similar in either case except that the logic operator changes between ">" or ">=". I would like to learn a way to simplify this and not have to include the same "action" code twice without creating a function for it. My intuition tells me that I am looking for a way to change the logical operator ">" to ">=" (or vice versa) depending on whether A or B is true, but I cannot find anything online about this capability. If simplifying this is impossible, then I can resort to maintaining what I have and simply making the "action" code into a function, if that is considered best practice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you merge the conditions? Something like this:

```py
if (conditionA and x > y) or (conditionB and x >= y):
    # perform your action
```

Comment: I mainly wanted to know what the best practice to achieve this was, and this seems to be the most elegant and concise approach. Sorry if it seemed like a stupid question, thank you!

Comment: @LP2LP I understand your point. And in Python, you can't change the comparison operators on the fly. I am glad that this seems to be the most elegant and concise approach to you. Can you please accept this answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your “same action” in a function, and merge the conditions instead of nesting them, for instance:

```python
def action():
    # perform your action
    ...

if condition_a and x > y:
    action()
elif condition_b and x >= y:
    action()
```

You can also merge both conditions into a single one

```python
if (
    (condition_a and x > y) or
    (condition_b and x >= y)
):
    # perform your action
```

There is not much more I see from the information you provided. Do not try to “simplify” too much if that would hinder readability.